# Stop file download if session is closed

Tags: session, cron, download, php

Is there a way to link/tie file downloads (uploads) to the user session?

What i want to achieve is that if user is downloading a file from a web service he can only do so while logged in.

Any unfinished downloads should stop if the session stops or if the user is blacklisted for that content (during the download).

The use case justifying this behavior is not easy to explain but the consequence of,

I have tried some PHP download managers like [Thingie](http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/).

The only working method I have so far is to create a temporary file for each download and deleting the file after the download or when the session is closed or user permission on the original file is denied.

Between the cron jobs and all the memory manipulation plus some issues with cash management I hope there is a more elegant way to do that.

I have also tried [register_shutdown_function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php)

Comment: You could use symlinks for your temporary files if you're not already doing it. You won't have to copy the files then.

Comment: PHP is probably not a great fit here. You'd need an evented system, in which a manager has an overview of running processes and what session/user those processes are associated with, then when a session is closed an event needs to be triggered which allows the manager to kill the associated process(es). Not something that's easily done in PHP.